# Prevent request to wait more than 10s if api doesn't respond

Tags: node.js, rest, settimeout

I saw that if a request has no response, it waits more then 60s. 
In my case I have nested async loop, managed with callbacks and promise. Each element is a api call. 
So I want to detect for example if an api don't respond after 10seconds to go ahead.

My code for the api requests :

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var  start = moment();
        const req = adapterFor(url).request(options, (resp) => {
        //console.log(`El pr ${options.path}`);
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });


            resp.on('end', () => {
                try {
                tmpData = JSON.parse(data.trim());
                if(tmpData.length != 0 && tmpData.films.length > 0) {
                    data = tmpData.films.filter(v => {
                        return v.film_o.length > 0
                    })
                    resolve(data);
                }else resolve({"Errore" : url,error:some error',error_type:'some error',duration: ((moment() - start) / 1000)+' s'});
                }catch (e) {
                    resolve({"Errore" : url,'error':'HERE MAYBE',error_type:'?!',duration: ((moment() - start) / 1000)+' s'});
                }
                // console.log(colors.gray("EL: " + tmpData.DS.Scheduling.Events.length.length));
            });

        });

        req.end();
    })
```

Comment: In the case do you want to break the `adapterFor(url).request` request after 10s?

Comment: Something like reject() if request takes more then 10s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to indicate a flag to reject after the time configured. In the example below you can see that the variable *reqHasFinished* is changed inside the request callback, so in case its keeps false you can reject the request:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let start = moment(),
        reqHasFinished = false;
    const req = adapterFor(url).request(options, (resp) => {
        reqHasFinished = true;
        let data = '';
        // resp operations here
    });

    // if after 10 seconds the request has not finished, the promise is rejected.   
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!reqHasFinished) {
            reject('Go ahead');
        }
    }, 10000)

    req.end();
});
```

Comment: That is what I think initially and it seems be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

If you can utilize ESnext then you can use Promise.race(). Consider the following example:

```
Promise.race([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 10000))
]).then(res => console.log(res))
```

You can provide multiple promises in an Array and Promise.race will always choose the fastest and resolve this one. So you can take your promise as one element and a timeout as shown above as the second. This promise will then always resolve after the timeout, or when your api call is done. Whatever is first will be resolved.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

https://jsfiddle.net/yLv64zr5/

Comment: Good but I can't apply it in my case.